# ROR application with Mysql 5.6 - transaction-isolation with Master -Slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

We are running a ROR application with Mysql 5.6 and master/slave replication. We are facing deadlock issues.

We've successfully tested changing settings from `REPEATABLE-READ` to `READ-COMMITTED` on our test servers (which are standalone; not master/slave) which has eliminated the deadlock problem:

```
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
```

When we added the same in the `my.cnf` file on both master and slave, not only does the replication fail but the application also fails to load.

What would be the recommended setting to accommodate this change. Is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at it in a different way...

- Are the transactions running longer than a second?  If so, rethink them.
- Do you test for errors and rerun a transaction if there is a Deadlock?

If it is not too big, let's see the transaction and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.